# Woking on block of text with sed while changed delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have curious issue that I can't figure out...

Lets say we have variable:

```
_file="/var/log/messages"
```

and file containing also this block:

```
/var/log/secure /var/log/messages /var/log/cron /var/log/maillog {
    compress
    monthly
    rotate 6
    create 600
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/*syslog*.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

I need a sed command that would select this specific block which contain the $_file at the start and ending with } and than do something in it.... lets say remove the $_file from it..

First issue is that its path so we need to change delimiter in sed

```
 sed -e "s|$_file[[:space:]]||" tests_file.txt
```

above will work, but I need to specify the block, normally it should look like:

```
sed -e "|$_file|,|\}|{s|$_file[[:space:]]||}"
```

but that always fail with:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'
```

Any idea whats going on ?

Comment: try with single quotes `sed -e 's|$_file[[:space:]]||' tests_file.txt`

Comment: @RomeoNinov same issue, I mean if you use s at the start of the sed command then it works, but that doesn't solve the "work only with this block" issue

Comment: try to use different symbol like: ` sed -e "s@$_file[[:space:]]@@" tests_file.txt`

Comment: already did try @ and #... same results, more and more I'm noticing how sed have problems with file paths when passed as variable into it... I can make it work if I siple not use variable and escape the / but that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `s` you can choose a delimiter in a straightforward way. It can be

```
s/a/b/
s|a|b|
sxaxbx
```

The chosen character must be a single-byte character though.

When specifying regex as an address, it's somewhat less straightforward:

```
/regex/
\cregexc
```

where `c` is any single-byte character. This means if you choose `|`, you need to escape it before `regex`, but not after.

```
sed -e "\|$_file|,\|\}|{s|$_file[[:space:]]||}" tests_file.txt
#       ^   here  ^
```

This works with GNU `sed` in my Debian 9.

---

Your example is unfortunate though. A line with `$_file` is always within a block therefore `s` will *always* affect it. This is because if you try to put `$_file` outside of the block, it will start a *new* block.

More educative example:

```
sed -e "\|$_file|,\|\}| s|a|X|g" tests_file.txt
```

This will change every `a` to `X` within a block. If you put a line containing `a` outside of any block, it will not be affected. (Note I dropped `{` and `}` embracing `s`. In this simple case they are not needed.)

Comment: I love you ! Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

The '/'es in your _file variable confuse sed as it uses the '/' as a delimiter for the addresses as well as the substitute delimitors.
You need to change the delimiter (e.g. to `|` ) whereby the first delimiter of each address must be escaped (like this `\|`) :

```
sed -e "\|.*$_file .*{$|,\|^}$|s|$_file ||" test_file.txt
```

Comment: bummer, took to much time to type. :-(